# Reducing table size during initial load with ADR in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019, azure-sql-managed-instance

When a table is created, and loaded with data from scratch based on a file, the table size changes significantly when Accelerated Database Recovery is on in SQL Server (realized based on my question here, [Table size in Azure SQL Managed Instance vs On Premise SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265446/table-size-in-azure-sql-managed-instance-vs-on-premise-sql-server))

Is there any way (perhaps via a hint) to reduce table size in a database with ADR on (as it cannot be turned off in our case) only during an initial load? There is no possibility of conflict during this initial load, and all of the relevant data can be loaded at once.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you measuring the table size?

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I use EXEC sp_spaceused 'tableName';

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any significant difference in this test.

```
create database nonadr
ALTER DATABASE nonadr SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = OFF

create database adr
ALTER DATABASE adr SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = ON;

go

with q as
(select top (1000*1000*10) *
 from sys.messages m, sys.objects o
)
select *
into nonadr.dbo.test
from q;


with q as
(select top (1000*1000*10) *
 from sys.messages m, sys.objects o
)
select *
into adr.dbo.test
from q;

go

exec nonadr.sys.sp_spaceused 'test' 
exec adr.sys.sp_spaceused 'test'

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS database_name,
       (persistent_version_store_size_kb / 1024.) AS persistent_version_store_size_mb
FROM sys.dm_tran_persistent_version_store_stats
WHERE persistent_version_store_size_kb > 0;
```

outputs

```
name                 rows                 reserved           data               index_size         unused
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
test                 10000000             3352392 KB         3351944 KB         8 KB               440 KB

name                 rows                 reserved           data               index_size         unused
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------ ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
test                 10000000             3494856 KB         3494384 KB         8 KB               464 KB

database_name        persistent_version_store_size_mb
-------------------- ---------------------------------------
adr                  0.070312
```

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE test_adr;`  

`ALTER  DATABASE test_adr SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = ON;`  

`CREATE TABLE test_adr.dbo.sample (`
`col1 bigint NOT NULL,`
`col2 smallint NOT NULL,`
`col3 tinyint NOT NULL);`

`INSERT INTO test_adr.dbo.sample WITH (TABLOCK)
select t1.k , t1.k%32000, t1.k%100  from ( SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) as k from sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns a ) t1 where t1.k < 1000000;`

I create a 3 column table with 1M entries as above, with ADR it's ~34 MB, without it's ~20 MB. Ratio is pretty consistent as entries grow.

Comment: That's just the 14 bytes/row for the row version pointer you get with _either_ ADR or READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Thank you @David, great information that I read up on. Not much to do then.

Comment: Any table with billions of rows should probably use a clustered columnstore index if you want to optimize for storage space and query speed.